# How to merge two NSArray into one NSArray

Tags: swift, nsarray

I have two NSArray for example

> Arr1 = ["anw1...,.."], ["anw2...,..."],["anw3,..."],["anw4,..."]
>
> Arr2 =  ["arrm1","...."], ["arrm2",...], ["arrm3",...], ["arrm4",...], ["arrm5",...]

How can I combine `Arr1` and `Arr2` NSArrays into one NSArray like example below?.

Output of `newarr` :

> Newarr = ["anw1...,.."], ["arrm1","...."], ["arrm2",...],
>   ["arrm3",...], ["arrm4",...],
>   ["arrm5",...],["anw2...,..."],["arrm1","...."], ["arrm2",...],
>   ["arrm3",...], ["arrm4",...],
>   ["arrm5",...],["anw3,..."],["arrm1","...."], ["arrm2",...],
>   ["arrm3",...], ["arrm4",...],
>   ["arrm5",...],["anw4,..."],["arrm1","...."], ["arrm2",...],
>   ["arrm3",...], ["arrm4",...], ["arrm5",...]

Comment: Why are you using NSArray in Swift?

Comment: @Tj3n i use nsarray to get value from json array

Comment: Why not use Swift Array? It's much easier to work with

Comment: Are the items in arr1 strings, or arrays of strings? What about arr2?

Comment: @DuncanC combine of string and int

Answer (score 1):

Wait, what? You want the first element of arr1, then ALL The elements of arr2, then the 2nd element of arr1, then all the elements of arr2 again, and so on?

As others have said, don't use NSArrays from Swift. Use Swift arrays.

Second, variable names should start with lower case letters, so Arr1 should be arr1 instead, and Arr2 should be arr2.

Then your code could look like this:

```
var result: [String] = []

let arr1 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
let arr2 = ["filler1", "filler2", "filler3", "filler4"]

for item in arr1 {
  result.append(item)
  result.append(contentsOf: arr2)
}
```

Comment: yes. u get what i means. just an example so i just simply write. I saw ppl suggest me don't use nsarray. But actually the value store in array is something like  {"ans_id": "1","ans_num": "336","answer": [{ "data_id": "1","num": "336", "data_word": ".."}, { "data_id": "2","lang_id": "2","num": "336", "data_word": "..." },] }, {  "ans_id": "2", "ans_num": "337","answer": [{ "data_id": "3","lang_id": "1","num": "337","data_word": "..."}, { "data_id": "4", "lang_id": "2", "num": "337","data_word": "..." }]},

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
//MARK:- NSArray
let arrayOne = NSArray() //["4","5","7"]
let arrayTwo = NSArray() //["8","9","10"]
var arrayResult = NSArray()

arrayResult = arrayOne.addingObjects(from: arrayTwo as! [Any]) as NSArray

print(arrayResult) //OutPut:- ["4","5","7","8","9","10"]

//MARK:- NSMutableArray
let arrayOne = NSMutableArray() //["4","5","7"]
let arrayTwo = NSMutableArray() //["8","9","10"]
var arrayResult = NSArray()

arrayResult = arrayOne.addingObjects(from: arrayTwo as! [Any]) as! NSMutableArray

print(arrayResult) //OutPut:- ["4","5","7","8","9","10"]
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
var Arr1 = [["anw1...,.."], ["anw2...,..."],["anw3,..."],["anw4,..."]]

var Arr2 = [["arrm1,...."], ["arrm2,..."], ["arrm3,..."], ["arrm4,..."], ["arrm5,..."]]



let Arr = Arr1 + Arr2
print(Arr)
```

//outPut:   [["anw1...,.."], ["anw2...,..."], ["anw3,..."], ["anw4,..."], ["arrm1,...."], ["arrm2,..."], ["arrm3,..."], ["arrm4,..."], ["arrm5,..."]]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new NSArray and make it a combination of the two

```
let ar1:NSArray = [3, 5, 7]
let ar2:NSArray = [4, 6, 8]
let ar3 = ar1.addingObjects(from: ar2 as! [Any])

print(ar3)
```

Should output `[3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8]`

Realistically though, you shouldn't have to use an NSArray with Swift.